# Linearizing a constraint with a root square

Tags: linear-transformations, linear-programming, operations-research, linearization

I have a Mixed Integer Model. In order to solve it using CPLEX, I need to linearize the non-linear constraint stated in the following.

Let $X_{i,j,t}$ is binary variable. How to linearized the following constraint:

$m\geq \sum_{i,j \in A}\mu _{i,j}X_{i,j,t}+z_\alpha \sqrt{\sum_{i,j \in A}\sigma_{i,j}^2X_{i,j,t}}$

Where $\mu _{i,j},z_\alpha,m$ and  $\sigma_{i,j}$ are positive known parameters of the problem

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is $m$ a variable or a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to rewrite as
$$m - \sum_{i,j \in A}\mu _{i,j}X_{i,j,t} \ge z_\alpha \sqrt{\sum_{i,j \in A}\sigma_{i,j}^2X_{i,j,t}},$$
square both sides,
and linearize the resulting products of binary variables in [the usual way](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables).

You might need to additionally impose
$$m \ge \sum_{i,j \in A}\mu _{i,j}X_{i,j,t}$$
to avoid extraneous solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am confused about the part of linearizing the resulting products of binary variables. When I square both sides in the LHS it gives a nonlinear part following: $ \left(\sum_{i,j \in A}\mu _{i,j}X_{i,j,t}\right) ^2 $. Does this mean products of two binary variables? I am not sure about that.

Comment: Yes, expanding that square yields several products of binary variables. Also, your question and comment contradict about whether $m$ is a constant or a variable.